# Site not loading on IOS?

Tags: html, css, ios

Since I don't have an `Iphone`. I have to test my site using site that there's available IOS tester.

I have reports that the site is not loading properly on Iphone.

Link: https://adthrone.com

But in the android version it works properly.

But in IOS not working properly

This is some details about the reports

- The whole index.php is not loading (Blank page)
- Sometimes it loads but some parts of the css/html of the page is missing.Like site logo in the navigational bar.
- Sometimes the `index.php` loads but have multiple html/css issues
- Android version works properly but not IOS.

The client has the following

- Good internet connection
- Have android & iphone for testing

Currently the site contains the ff:

- Low quality images with file size of `KB`
- Used bootstrap for front end

I just want to know the facts why this site is unstable when it comes to IOS mobile version.

Comment: Check your CSS files, you may need to optimize your website's CSS to work in Safari